# Using paperclip with imagemagick on macosx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, passenger

I am trying to use paperclip on macosx with phusion passenger. When i try to make an upload, apache give me :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libtiff.3.dylib requires version 13.0.0 or later, but libjpeg.8.dylib provides version 12.0.0
```

But when i run my rails application with **rails server**, everything works fine. When i try to use the **identify** command in my terminal as well.

Paperclip give me this error :

```
/Var/Folders/Nj/9xt2kprd01n3ssch3rd44pmh0000gn/T/Stream20120222-92627-1l2u297.Png Is Not Recognized By The 'Identify' Command.
```

Any idea? I am using MacOsx Lion

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having a similar issue with ffmpeg on MaxOsx Lion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107671/ffmpeg-mamp-dyld-library-not-loaded-error

Comment: Hello, no i don't, i forgave...When i want to use this, i launch the rails server and no phusion.

Comment: Similar problem here, perhaps. Used to work, but now: `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtiff.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: image not found`

Answer (score 2):

Further to my comment, I just had a similar problem and solved it as follows (not sure if this will work for you).

As per [this homebrew/imagemagick issue](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/12099), precompiled binaries may reference the wrong library versions when something else is upgraded.

Therefore, recompiling Imagemagick from source may help. For my own install, via Homebrew, this did it:

```
> brew uninstall imagemagick
> brew install imagemagick --build-from-source
```

My guess is that in your case Apache and/or Passenger may be calling a different version of Imagemagick, or operating as a different user with different load paths and therefore not finding the library.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this same issue on OS X 10.8 and reinstalling `imagemagick` from source had no effect but reinstalling `libtiff` from source did. yay! :)

```
brew uninstall libtiff
brew install libtiff --build-from-source
```

I found this out by using `otool -L` which showed that somehow libtiff was pointing to a newer version of libjpeg than installed on my system. reinstalling it from source causes it to link against the older version.

hope that helps!